# Concatenate doesn't seem to be working on azure

Tags: azure, function, t-sql, ssms

On an Azure database in Sql-server-management-studio: I get 'CONCATENATE' is not recognized as a built-in function, but it is highlighted in blue, as if it recognizes it as a function:

```
SELECT CONCATENATE(cOLUMN_nAME,',') AS A
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'_PPL_DETAIL'
```

I have a way to do it:

```
SELECT cOLUMN_nAME + ',' AS A
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'_PPL_DETAIL'
```

Question is, why doesn't the function work in Azure, as I may not always be needing to append a literal....I want to know for future needs...

Comment: Try `concat` instead of `concatenate`.

Comment: yes..  that worked.  I wonder why it marked it in blue if it did not detect it as a function...

Comment: @KamMistry that's an interesting observation. I was curious, did a google search and found *mostly* nothing. CONCATENATE is an MS PowerApps function. I don't know anything about PowerApps nor understand its relationship to SQL Server but I noticed other PowerApps functions that are reserverd keywords in SQL Server Management Studio such a ATAN and ATN2 (ATAN2 is a SQL function, not ATN2)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `CONCAT` like this (SQL Server 2012 and above) :

```
SELECT CONCAT(COLUM_NAME,',') AS A
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'_PPL_DETAIL'
```

You can also use `COALESCE` like this :

```
 SELECT COALESCE(COLUM_NAME,',') AS A
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'_PPL_DETAIL'
```